# Movie about a man who uses blood of predecessor to protect doorways

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie as a child but have never been able to find the title.  I believe its about vampires, zombies or something similar.

Key scenes include:

- Can only kill the monsters by stabbing/shooting them in the eyes. 
  One dies by deer antler impalement.
- The hero carries a magical container that holds the blood of the
  previous carrier.  The blood is used to deter the monsters.  It was
  mostly used to spread on doorways to prevent their passage.
- Said magical container has several glyphs (stars?) on it that glow as
  the hero comes closer to whomever will inherit its powers when the
  current carrier dies.
- The container makes an imprint on the carrier's hand.
- Towards the end the hero dies and passes on the magical container and
  fills it with his blood with his dying breaths. The new carrier
  covers herself in the blood as a sort of immunity to the monsters but
  gets wrapped in a bath curtain as one point rendering the blood
  useless.

Can anyone help me name this movie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This seems like Tales from the Crypt: Demon Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Knight).

The ancestor whose blood is in the container is none other than Jesus Christ, and the monsters were demons.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds a lot like Tales from the Crypt: Demon Knight. [Here is a synopsis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Knight).

Comment: That is correct, but Jen beat you to it.